# WebKit ProcessAssertion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio-player

I coded a music application using Xcode 10 because I'm still on High-Sierra. I have installed the latest iOs 13.4.1 update and I can run the app from Xcode so everything is fine. This app has a 1x1 pixel webview allowing to stream a m3u playlist, so it's invisible for the user who will use the app but the sound launches without any problem.

Here is my issue. Every time I launch the app, once I lock the screen, the sound is muted. I could also see this error message in the console:

```
[ProcessSuspension] Background task expired while holding WebKit ProcessAssertion (isMainThread? 1).
```

What does this mean and is there a way to fix the problem?

I've had several answers to this: some say it's a bug, some say it's a resource issue, others think it's the latest version and we have to wait for Apple to fix the problem themselves.